# Number of vertices with degree more than $\sqrt{|E|}$

Tags: graph-theory

Playing around, it seems for graph $G$ there is most $\sqrt{|E|}$ vertices with degree more than $\sqrt{|E|}$. Using sum of degrees is proof at most $2\sqrt{|E|}$ such vertices. But I cannot find proof (or counter) for stronger claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't true, I'm afraid. Let $K_n=(V,E)$ be the complete graph with $\lvert V\rvert=n$, for $n$ large enough. Then $\lvert E\rvert=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$, hence $\sqrt{\lvert E\rvert}<\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}$. But the degree of any vertex is $n-1>\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}$, and there are $n>\frac{n}{\sqrt{2}}$ vertices.